# How to clone a prototype with property methods?

Tags: javascript, prototype, clone

I am using the Typed.React library which includes a method to extend one prototype definition with that of another:

```
function extractPrototype(clazz) {
    var proto = {};
    for (var key in clazz.prototype) {
        proto[key] = clazz.prototype[key];
    }
    return proto;
}
```

If the provided class defines property methods, this function has a side effect of executing the get method e.g.

```
var TestObject = (function () {
    function TestObject() {
        this.str = "test string";
    }
    Object.defineProperty(TestObject.prototype, "TestProperty", {
        get: function () {
            console.log("exec get");
            return this.str;
        },
        set: function (value) {
            console.log("exec set");
            this.str = value;
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
    return TestObject;
})();

var extracted = extractPrototype(TestObject);
```

When extactPrototype accesses TestObject.prototype["TestProperty"], it will execute the property get method and print:

```
exec get
```

How would I duplicate a prototype with property methods without executing them?

Comment: Is there a problem with `Object.create()`?

Comment: You can use TestObject as prototype of new object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the new ES6 [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) function.

Of course there's a simpler fix to your problem - just don't access and set properties, copy their [property descriptors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor):

```
function extractPrototype(clazz) {
    var proto = {};
    for (var key in clazz.prototype) {
        Object.defineProperty(proto, key, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(clazz.prototype, key));
    }
    return proto;
}
```

Comment: Does the result of this differ from the original version in any other way besides not executing the get method? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it also copies the `writable` and `configurable` attributes of each property.

Comment: Ah, I think this breaks methods. How about this:             var getter = clazz.prototype.__lookupGetter__(key);
            var setter = clazz.prototype.__lookupSetter__(key);
       
            if ( getter || setter ) {
                Object.defineProperty(proto, key, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(clazz.prototype, key));
            }
            else {
                proto[key] = clazz.prototype[key];
            }

Comment: @daw: What do you mean by "this breaks methods"? And `__lookup%etter__` are deprecated since years.